# How to read option parameters on PHP [Cordova file uploading]?

Tags: php, android, cordova

I'm uploading image file using phonegap.I want to read option parameters on PHP file how can I do it?

This is my mobile application code.

```
    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
}
```

This is my upload.php file

```
    <?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = uniqid().uniqid ().".jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "image/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

How to read bellow values on php file

```
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options.params` should be read as a `POST`, this should display them:

```
print_r($_POST);
```